# Database update weirdness

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am developing a game in Django in which the quantity of rebels updates after a turn change. Rebels are represented as integers from 0 to 100 in the (MySQL) database.

When I save, this happens:

```
print world.rebels
>>> 0

rebstab = 0
world.rebels += rebstab
world.save()

print world.rebels
>>> 0
```

However, when I use F() expressions (as I gather I should to prevent race conditions), this happens:

```
print world.rebels
>>> 0

rebstab = 0
world.rebels = F('rebels') + rebstab
world.save()

print world.rebels
>>> 100
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the reason had nothing to do with the F() object itself but rather a conflict with a custom save method. See [Django F() objects and custom saves weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200450/django-f-objects-and-custom-saves-weirdness) for a more indepth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with using `F()` objects like this so this answer may not be useful, but [having a look at the documentation it mentions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions):

> In order to access the new value that has been saved in this way, the object will need to be reloaded:
>
> ```
> reporter = Reporters.objects.get(pk=reporter.pk)
> ```

so you may have to actually query the DB again to see the updated value:

```
print world.rebels
>>> 0

rebstab = 0
world.rebels = F('rebels') + rebstab
world.save()

print World.objects.get(pk=world.pk)
>>> 100
```

**Edit:** Also look [at the example where you don't need to pull the objects into memory and can do everythign at the DB level:

```
World.objects.get(pk=...).update(rebels=F('rebels) + 1)
```

Comment: Except the value _has_ been updated, as I'm getting a different value. However, I have no clue why I'm getting the maximum amount of rebels when I set the change to 0. I should state that this update is visible in the rest of the game and the admin, so it's not an issue limited to this particular function.

Comment: The DB has been updated but the object you have in memory may not have been as the F() introduces an SQL call which *might not* (again I'm not 100% sure) update to the object. Also note my update

Comment: I can't do pure SQL updates as I have a custom save method. Also as stated, the issue is not limited to this function, so object conflict between memory and database cannot be the issue.

Comment: Read the docs, when you use an `F()` object you are creating an SQL expression: `When Django encounters an instance of F(), it overrides the standard Python operators to create an encapsulated SQL expression; in this case, one which instructs the database to increment the database field represented by reporter.stories_filed.` so be aware that this might be causing an issue.

Comment: How is this an issue? A simple increment is all I want to do, world.rebels is an IntegerField and rebstab is an integer. Are you telling me that + within an F() object means something different?

Comment: Yes. `Whatever value is or was on reporter.stories_filed, Python never gets to know about it `. The F() expression simply tells Django to perform arithmetic on the DB level using the field within the F() expression. This is unlike usual when the object is read from the DB, the object is incremented (in python) and the object is saved back to the DB

Comment: But the increment is of the completely wrong value. Whether or not it is in Python memory is irrelevant.