# Django F() objects and custom saves weirdness

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been working with Django F() objects to update my models, in order to avoid race conditions.

I also have a custom save method for my model (I want rebels to range from 0 to 100).

Here is some example code:

```
class World(models.Model):
    ...
    world.rebels = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        if self.rebels > 100:
            self.rebels = 100
        elif self.rebels < 0:
            self.rebels = 0  
        ...
        super(World, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I have a function which adds a quantity to the rebel count.

```
world = World.objects.get(worldid=1)
rebchange = 0

print world.rebels
>>> 0

world.rebels = F('rebels') + rebchange

print world.rebels
>>> (+: (DEFAULT: ), 0)

world.save()

print world.rebels
>>> 100
```

How odd, right? The increment is of completely the wrong value! I then commented out the custom save method with the conditions involving self.rebels, and voila, the model then saves the correct value to the database. 
Obviously `(+: (DEFAULT: ), 0) > 100` is somehow `True`, and triggering the change to 100.

I've changed my custom save method to this:

```
def save(self, fsave=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if fsave == False:
        ...
        if self.rebels > 100:
            self.rebels = 100
        elif self.rebels < 0:
            self.rebels = 0  
        ...
    super(World, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And in my function, I then call world.save() twice:

```
world = World.objects.get(worldid=1)
rebchange = 0
world.rebels = F('rebels') + rebchange
world.save(fsave=True)
world.save()

print world.rebels
>>> 0
```

in order to be able to *avoid* my custom save when it's saving the F() object, and then enforce my custom save with the correct values.

Is this expected behaviour, and if so, is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing different types in Python, numbers always are sorted before other objects. Thus, `100` is always going to be lower than the `F()` object.

You'll indeed need to special-case testing for this; you could instead test if `self.rebels` is an instance of `F`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    if not isinstance(self.rebels, F):
        if self.rebels > 100:
            self.rebels = 100
        elif self.rebels < 0:
            self.rebels = 0  
    ...
    super(World, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Python 2 does this to support sorting lists of mixed types, while guaranteeing a stable sort order at the same time.

Because this behaviour could lead to subtle unexpected bugs (exactly like in your case), this behaviour has been removed in Python 3, and only types that support comparisons explicitly are supported.